# Is validates_presence_of used as default on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is `validates_presence_of` used as default for all attributes on save? So you don´t have to write it in your models every time?

[Here the reference to my question](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_presence_of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `validates_presence_of` is not used as default and you have to write it in your models every time for every attribute you want to be present.